# Jupyter Notebook : 'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I tried to view my CSV file using

```
!head {train_file_path}
```

in jupyter notebook.But it raises an error

```
'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

`!head{}` works in **colab** but not in Jupyter Notebook.

please help me, guys . 
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Using `!` means that you will be calling a system command. If you are on a `Linux/Unix` system (`Google Colab` uses such system) then you can call `Linux/Unix` commands directly using `!`. In this case, I am assuming that you are using a `Windows` system and the command `head` does not exist as a command for `Windows`. Assuming that you are using a locally hosted `Jupyter Notebook`, then it is running on a `Windows` system.

You can do something similar through Python using:

```
with open({train_file_path}) as f:
    for _ in range(10): # first 10 lines
        print(f.readline())
```

Comment: Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 3):

`%%bash` works for me

or

```
conda install posix
```

https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/203

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue even if I installed the Linux Subsystem for Windows and tried to refer Jupyter Lab to bash.exe. This seems to work for terminal sessions in Jupyter Lab, but not in the notebook cells.

A workaround for me was to add a `%%bash`
at the beginning of each cell with bash commands. Then also remove the `!` from the actual commands, like so

```
%%bash
head iris.csv
```

Still cannot make it work with an `!` directly, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Anaconda in windows:
For users like me following steps are recommended:

1.Go to your Anaconda Navigator
2. Inside environments click on the play button of base(root) and select open terminal
3. This is your conda environment terminal
4. Type:

```
conda install posix
```

5. after the installtion is finished go back to your jupyter notebook or lab and run the !head code again.
   It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56096658/12909159) answer.

You can replace cmd with powershell and use the `!gc yourfile.txt -TotalCount 10` command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
%alias head powershell -command "& {Get-Content %s -Head 5}"

%head datasets/transfusion.data
```